# How to implement a generic function to apply `crossterm` style to any type which can be converted into a string

Tags: rust, crossterm

I would like to implement a generic function to apply style `red` and attribute `bold` to any type which can be converted into a string.

This function works, but only for `&str` arguments:

```rust
use crossterm::style::Stylize;

fn red(str: &str) -> <&str as Stylize>::Styled {
    str.red().bold()
}
```

I would like this function to work for instance in the following cases:

```rust
println!("{}", red("test"));
println!("{}", red("test".to_owned()));
println!("{}", red(1+1));
```

In all three cases, red text should be printed to the terminal.
I tried the following implementation:

```rust
fn red<T: Stylize>(str: T) -> <T as Stylize>::Styled {
    str.red().bold()
}
```

but it does not compile, with message:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `bold` found for associated type `<T as Stylize>::Styled` in the current scope
  --> src\bin\orphanext-cli.rs:92:15
   |
92 |     str.red().bold()
   |               ^^^^ method not found in `<T as Stylize>::Styled`
```

I understand the meaning of the compiler message, but I cannot find a proper solution that works in all three cases listed above. Of course I would like the function to call `to_string()` only when necessary, so only for instance if I pass a `i32`, not if I pass a `&str` or a `String`.

In other words:

- When I provide a `&str` the function should behave as the following one:

```rust
fn red(str: &str) -> <&str as Stylize>::Styled {
    str.red().bold()
}
```

- When I provide a `String` the function should behave as the following one:

```rust
fn red(str: String) -> <String as Stylize>::Styled {
    str.red().bold()
}
```

- When I provide a `i32` (or any other type implementing trait `Display`) the function should behave as the following one:

```rust
fn red(num: i32) -> <String as Stylize>::Styled {
    num.to_string().red().bold()
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can return a regular `&str`. You probably have to wrap it in something, like `Styled::Red(Styled::Bold(s))`.

Comment: You should provide more code. For example, your implementation of Stylize/Styled or `use` if you used them and the desired output.